# PHP sleep() not working

Tags: php, sleep

I'm making a php file that will run an event after five minutes have elapsed.  From the docs, it seems like waiting five minutes would only require `sleep(300)`, but this isn't working.  I've tested all the other code, and it works fine until I add the `sleep` line.

```
<?php
/**
 * Twitter App
 * bagelBack.php
 * Takes parameters from $_POST and creates a tweet
 * RKoutnik, 2012
 * Code originally found on http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/hello-twitter-oauth-php/
 */

$name = '@'.$_POST['twitterName'];
$type =  $_POST['bagelType'];

/* BEGIN CONTENT SPINNER TO IMPRESS LYNK */
$bagels = array(
    0 => "bagel",
    1 => "breakfast treat",
    2 => "doughy food-type item",
    3 => "round yeast-raised munchie",
    4 => "doughnut-shaped roll",
    5 => "hard-crusted treat"
);
$finished = array(
    0 => "finished toasting",
    1 => "completed toasting",
    2 => "stopped being raw",
    3 => "concluded the toasting phase",
    4 => "been sucessfully executed",
    5 => "been roasted to a crisp"
);

$food = $bagels[array_rand($bagels)];
$fin = $finished[array_rand($finished)];
sleep(300);
$tweet_text = $name.", Your ".$type." ".$food." has ".$fin;

$result = post_tweet($tweet_text);
echo "Response code: " . $result . "\n";

function post_tweet($tweet_text) {

  // Use Matt Harris' OAuth library to make the connection
  // This lives at: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth
  require_once('tmhOAuth.php');

  // Set the authorization values
  // In keeping with the OAuth tradition of maximum confusion, 
  // the names of some of these values are different from the Twitter Dev interface
  // user_token is called Access Token on the Dev site
  // user_secret is called Access Token Secret on the Dev site
  // The values here have asterisks to hide the true contents 
  // You need to use the actual values from Twitter
  $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => '[redacted]',
    'consumer_secret' => '[redacted]',
    'user_token' => '[redacted]',
    'user_secret' => '[redacted]',
    'curl_ssl_verifypeer'   => false
  )); 

  // Make the API call
  $connection->request('POST', 
    $connection->url('1/statuses/update'), 
    array('status' => $tweet_text)
  );

  return $connection->response['code'];
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Does the PHP script stop working completely when you have the sleep() call? Does it sleep, but not for five minutes?

Comment: It doesn't work at all.  It doesn't post anything to twitter, like it should.

Comment: What is your `max_execution_time` in your php.ini? Maybe the script is just running too long and therefore exists before anything is done.

Comment: 30 seconds.  Yup, that was it.  Thanks, I didn't know that existed!

Comment: It would have been useful to mention whether this PHP was being executed by a web server or a command line.

Comment: @ghoti ok, I'll remember that for my next (inevitable) PHP question.  What's the difference?

Comment: Well, for one thing, your platform might have a different `max_execution_time` for CLI than for CGI/mod_php.  Ubuntu's PHP5 has /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.  But in general, environment affects behaviour, so the more information the better.  (Within reason of course.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of the document. Chances are it is reaching the "maximum execution time" and causing the script to terminate.

Comment: This sounds like it'll fix the problem, I'll let you know in five minutes if it worked.

Comment: Alternately, `set_time_limit(315);`, or 300+whatever your expected maximum execution time is.  If for some reason processes get stuck, it's better not to exhaust your process table by accident!