# PHP - Delay on redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I'm using the following code to use as a form of nulling referring script and it works perfectly but it just redirects them straight to the target URL.

How would I go about creating a 5 second delay so I can display some adverts for 5 seconds before redirecting them?

Comment: You can also use HTML: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://stackoverflow.com">`

Comment: Why you not use sleep() function?

Comment: The meta tag is the best way to go, as it pushes processing over the the browser, rather than tying up server resources for 5 seconds

Comment: hello! I am the owner of the accepted answer. However, the amount of upvotes the `meta refresh` answer has makes me think it may be worth unaccepting mine in favour of the other one.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can send php header with timeout refresh. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php 
  header( "refresh:5; url=wherever.php" ); 
?>
```

Comment: This is better than the above solution as it doesn't block the php process.

Comment: @krossovochkin there is no need to halt application, because the question  is how to redirect with delay, that means he want to show whole page, then redirect :)

Answer (score 7):

The `refresh` header does the job but I'd like to highlight some potential issues:

- It is not specified in the HTTP standard. Wikipedia says:

  > Proprietary and non-standard: a header extension introduced by Netscape and supported by most web browsers.

  But it has been around for almost 20 years now and I don't know of any browser that does *not* support it (could not find a reference though)
- Some browsers do not use the cache on a page redirected with `refresh`. It has been demonstrated for Internet Explorer here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/meta-refresh-causes-additional-http-requests.aspx and I coud reproduce it on Firefox. Chrome does not have this issue.

### Alternative: JavaScript

You can add a JavaScript on the intermediate page, that opens a new page after X seconds. Add this at the bottom of the page to redirect to `http://www.example.com/target` after `5` seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href='http://www.example.com/target';
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

### Combination

As a bonus, you can fall back to the `refresh` header if JS is disabled, using the `meta` directive `http-equiv` that tells the browser to act as if a certain HTTP header has been sent. Because it is part of the HTML source, you can wrap it in a `<noscript>` element. Add this to your `<head>` additionally to the JavaScript above:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/target" />
</noscript>
```

Now, the page redirects with JavaScript if available for the best performance, and uses `refresh` otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

What about using [sleep()](http://php.net/sleep)?

```
function method1(...) {

sleep(5);

... rest of the code
```

#### Note however that it is more recommended to use [Vahe Shadunts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955790/1983854), which uses `header()` instead.

Comment: That won't really work as sleep() will block output to the page (and keep the thread occupied while it's at it). Best bet is to use some form of javascript for this.

Comment: So that will delay the re-direct for 5 seconds?  Where abouts in the script would I put that?

Comment: Yes, it delays the re-direct for 5 seconds. You should put it before any redirect method is called, so for example before `switch ($_REQUEST['attempt']) {` line. Check it, as what @RickvanBodegraven is saying is quite interesting and I am curious about it.

Comment: So would i need to put it above every attempt?  Since there are 3 methods in that script I'd need to put it 3 times?

Comment: No, once is enough. Put it before the call of any method, well the mainstream of the code is. That's why I suggest putting it before `switch ($_REQUEST['attempt']) {`.

Comment: Oh I'm with you now, I'll try it out.  So I can just add some basic html adverts bellow all the PHP and the sleep(5) should make it stay on those adverts for 5 seconds before redirecting them.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, should be. Try it and come back to tell us if it worked!

Comment: It seems to be working but it seems to be taking 10 seconds before showing the link

Comment: Mmmm curious. Check if you wrote `sleep(5)` twice somewhere.

Comment: That is so curious. I suggest checking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998178/php-sleep-not-working, when suggest to put `set_time_limit(0);` in the beginning. You can also try with `header( "refresh:5; url=wherever.php" );`, as suggested by @Vahe Shadunts.

Comment: If I were to put the header refresh method would I need to use it in every method?