# Is there a way to redirect to another page in php without using header()?

Tags: php

Is there a way to redirect to another page in php without using header()? I can't use header() because I am outputting some stuff first to the page. I've considered using Javascript's window.location but I'm using an if statement in php so is there any way in php to go to another page without using header()? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955526/php-delay-on-redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't use header() because I am outputting some stuff first to the page.

You shouldn't dismiss using `header()`. Using `header()` is still achievable by using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

For example:

```
<?php

ob_start(); //start the buffer
echo "This is some output"; //Output data
ob_clean(); //Erase the buffer content
header('Location: http://google.com'); //Redirect user
```

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP? No.

You already mentioned using JS and window.location.

The only other option is [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Examples):

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">`

Comment: You mean like my comment?

Comment: @JelledeFries no, not really.

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry I only read the comment of that question. but we meant the same, I just didn't say it, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at cURL especially curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);