# Return Redirect with body in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to do a redirect with body in Laravel. I've tried this:

```
return Redirect::to($log_in_url)->with('body','<html><head><title>Redirecting to your page</title></head><body>If you are not redirected within 5 seconds, please <a href="'.$log_in_url.'">cl ick here</a>.</body></html>');
```

I look in the network tab, I don't really see anything.

The question is that how would one make a delayed redirection by showing an HTML waiting page before the actual redirection happens?

Comment: Laravel doesn't put the `with` in the body of the redirect, it actually puts it in the session and shares it with the view after the redirect (so it's available when you've been redirected). It is a bit misleading but I'm not aware of any modern browser who would actually see the redirection text.

Comment: My suggestion is to rollback a bit and think about what you're trying to do which would warrant the need for a redirect response with an HTML body. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @apokryfos This is indeed a case for XY problem. I edited the question and tried making it a bit clearer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955526/php-delay-on-redirect is a good read here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a handful of false assumptions:

- The `with` method puts the thing into the session so that you can access it **after** the redirection. A common usecase is to set messages and then redirect the user.
- Don't expect magic by just setting the thing `body`.
- There's no such a standardized redirection called *"redirect with body"* as you stated. If you need such a thing, you have to implement it.

I assume you're having one of those vBulletin-like redirect styles in mind. To implement it in Laravel context, you gonna need a mediatory view to do a clientside redirect for you after a set amount of delay. Let's name it `redirect.blade.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <script>
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "{{ $url }}";
        }, 5000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    If you are not redirected within 5 seconds, 
    please <a href="{{ $url }}">click here</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

With this in place, your controller will pass a `$url` to this mediatory view and let it be rendered to do the clientside redirection:

```
# Controller method
return view('redirect', ['url' => $log_in_url])
```

This style of redirection won't be working if JavaScript is disabled and that's why they put a link into the page content and warn the user about it.

Some take a hybrid approach:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url={{ $url }}" />
</noscript>
```

The reason that they don't go with the refresh header/meta tag in the first place is that it's not specified in the HTTP standard. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33009183/65732).

---

I strongly suggest that you look into alternatives. This is so 1990 and not user-friendly at all.

As a visitor, if I deal with a website that makes me wait for 5 godddamn seconds, I'd just leave. That's why people used to make browser extensions to workaround the vBulletin's login screen waiting time!

Embrace simplicity and just do a regular HTTP redirect. It's best for all humanity.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a task for Laravel. You can just return page with meta, or using javascript.

```
// Controller
return view('redirect'); 

// View redirect.blade (Regular html page with additional meta tag)
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.google.com/" />
```