# Need help regarding wordpress functions.php code which is used for redirections

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I would highly appreciate it if you could help me with inserting the redirection code.
I am using the following script to redirect the old website to the new one on the same post path.
I insert that script in Wordpress functions.php and the script works perfectly in redirecting.

I want that script to be executed after 5 seconds delay..
i mean the visitor while reading the post redirects to the same post on another website after 5 seconds,
I meant to say the user stay on the same post page for 5 seconds before redirecting to the other website's same post.

EXAMPLE: [www.MyWebSite.com/Post123](http://www.MyWebSite.com/Post123)
visitor stay on the /Post123 for 5 seconds and then
redirects to [www.OtherWebSite.com/Post123](http://www.OtherWebSite.com/Post123)

please help .. following is the code. I would highly appreciate it if you could do me a favor by responding on my question by modifying the code I have given below so I can copy and paste it into wordpress editor functions.php.. Thanks a lot.

```
 function redirect_posts() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type=='post') {
        return header('location:https://www.MYWEBSITE.com/'.$post->post_name);
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'redirect_posts');
```

Comment: Why do you want to wait before redirecting? That sounds like a bad user experience when you could just redirect immediately in .htaccess without even loading the page.

Comment: actually i am trying to redirect traffic from my website which is ranked on google search. and i have installed a duplicate database of my ranked site to the new domain which i want to use from now. if the user redirects immediately then it will Harm the ranking of my old website over search engines, so i want the visitor to stay on same post for at least 5 seconds before getting redirected to the same post on my other site. hope you understand my issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Delay on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955526/php-delay-on-redirect)

Comment: @CBroe
no it does not answer my question.

Comment: i want the code which redirects visitors to the different website but the same path ..
for example : www.Example1.com/Post123  to www.Example2.com/Post123

Comment: It _does_ answer the question about the delay you wanted. If you are still missing anything now - then you should probably put in a bit of research effort, or at least tell us what the ones you made so far have turned up. This is not a "gimme code, make this for me" site.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and i suggested can you use Redirection plugin.

This plugin is used for 301 redirects and many conditional causes.

You can read plugin documentation for  [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).